# what data are stored in developer profile file exported from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

As we know, from `Organizer->Devices->Teams->Team Name` we can export file that have extenstion "developerprofile". What data are stored in such file? Only certificates for each team member or whole settings that are in Xcode (like shortcuts etc). What happen when you import some other team member developer profile? Is it like Xcode is "signed" to his name/certificate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The filename.developerprofile file generated by Xcode 5 after opening Preferences -> Accounts and then selecting "Export Accounts..." from the little gear menu is a zip file that contains the following structure:

```
developer
developer/accounts.keychain
developer/accounts.plist
developer/identities
developer/identities/0163571FCC272FCXXXXXDA9D68F13A5194FE4245.p12
developer/profiles
developer/profiles/049DB4B6-2417-4514-1234-F60C189A5641.mobileprovision
```

The p12 files are private keys that are protected by the password that you specified when exporting the developerprofile from xcode. The mobileprovision files contain the certificates for signing your binaries.

You can unzip the developerprofile file by changing the extension to .zip or from the command line using `unzip filename.developerprofile`